# How to use a Rigidbody on a game object after animation in Unity?

Tags: unity, physics, animation

How to use a Rigidbody on a game object after animation in Unity?

I want to play an animation fully controlling the positioning of the elements, i.e. ignoring physics. And after an animation plays till the end I want physics to resume affecting the element.

Right now to get the expected behavior I have to remove the **Animator** after an animation. I thought that maybe there is a neater way to do what I want, but I did not find it, so decided to ask here.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I just found a better way to achieve what I want. Instead of removing the **Animator** component I just disable it:

```
animator.enabled = false;
```

It feels better. But still I am hoping for a neater solution.

Comment: Have you tried isKinematic ? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html (I am still on my first or second readthrough of the manual and haven't tested it myself yet).

Comment: @Emil, it seems your comment has nothing to do with my question. Otherwise, could you elaborate it, please?

Comment: @some1here `Is Kinematic` If enabled, the object will not be driven by the physics engine, and can only be manipulated by its Transform. This is useful for moving platforms or if you want to animate a Rigidbody that has a HingeJoint attached.

Comment: Your "Update" should be posted as an Answer - it's worth an upvote on its own. Don't worry, even an answered question can still get other answers, so you won't be blocking alternative solutions. (Though myself, I'd say this is exactly the situation `animator.enabled = false` exists to serve)

Comment: @DMGregory, yeah. You are reading my mind. I wanted to get an answer, so I did not post the update as one :)

Comment: @Zibelas, but in my case I want the rigidbody to be affected by physics...

Comment: @DMGregory, I am trying to avoid using a script here whatsoever by unticking the enablement checkbox of an **Animator** component in the end of the animation. I think I will post an answer after I will figure it out.

Comment: @some1 here IsKinematic on while your animation is running, off when its done. Was my idea. Since it turns off and on physics (i.e. exactly what you asked?). But since I have never tested it I don't know if it works that way. But it sounds like your animation overrides the physics somehow so maybe the problem was the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make physics affect rigidbody after playing an animation we can disable an animator.

One way to do that is through the animation event which would call a script, which would disable the **Animator**:

```
//get an animator instance in any way
//e.g. through a property or through the .GetComponent<Animator>()
animator.enabled = false;
```

Another way is to disable an animator from animation itself. The **Animator** enablement checkbox seems to be an animatable property. But so far I was not able to do that.